# Minimum of Two Exponential Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> Elevator $A$ breaks down with an exponential distribution of $4$ per day, while elevator $B$ breaks down with an exponential distribution of $6$ per day. Assume a day begins at midnight. What is the probability that the first breakdown occurs before $2$ AM?

**My attempt:**

Let $X$ = the time between two consecutive breakdowns for elevator A and $Y$ = the time between two consecutive breakdowns for elevator B. Then $\min(X,Y)$ is exponentially distributed with rate $10$. Thus, let $Z = \min(X,Y)$, so $P(Z < 2) = 1-e^{-20} = 1$ approximately. My only issue with this is that $Z$ is the minimum time between two consecutive breakdowns, not a single breakdown.. Aren't I overcompensating? For example, my answer includes the probability that the elevator breaks down at $5$ AM and then breaks down again at $6$ AM. Also, the probability is $1$, which seems wrong as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of breakdowns of the first elevator in a day has a **Poisson** distribution with a mean of $4.$ The thing that has an exponential distribution is the time until the next breakdown, which has an expected value of $1/4\text{ day}.$ With the two elevators together the mean waiting time is $1/10\text{ day}.$

Since $2\text{ hours} = 1/12\text{ day},$ the probability that it happens within that time is $1- e^{-(1/12)/(1/10)} = 1 - e^{-10/12} \approx 0.5654.$

One would speak here not of the minimum of two exponential distributions, but of the minimum of two exponentially distributed random variables.

Comment: Ahh.. I see.. so I confused the Poisson rate with the exponential rate then? I'm still a bit confused.. If I write the CDF in the form $1-$$e^{-λx}$, then what does $λ$ represent?

Comment: @Saad : I'd call it a "rate" either way, but maybe an "average" or "expected value" when talking about the Poisson distribution. The Poisson distribution is the _discrete_ distribution of the number of breakdowns, within the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ and the exponential distribution is the _continuous_ distribution of the time until the next breakdown.

Comment: So in our situation, the mean waiting time is $1/10$ day? But then wikipedia says that if you write the CDF in terms of the mean, it would be $1-$$e^{-10x}$ as per the alternative parameterization section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

where $x$ is the time in days before the next occurence

Comment: @Saad : Right. The time in days is $1/12.$ so $1-e^{-10x} = 1 - e^{-10/12}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the rates are $4$ breakdowns per $24$ hours and $6$ breakdowns per $24$ hours. Therefore, $\lambda_1 = \frac{4}{24}$, and $\lambda_2 = \frac{6}{24}$. Using them, you obtain
$$\Pr\{Z\le 2\} = 1-\exp(-20/24).$$

Comment: Wait.. if $X$~$exp(λ)$, where $λ$ is the rate, then $F(x) = 1-e^{-λx}$.. isn't the rate 10 in our case?

Comment: @Saad It is $(4+6)/24=10/24$.

Comment: @Saad : Proper MathJax code might be $$ X\sim \exp(\lambda), $$ although I would prefer $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ because often $\exp(\lambda)$ means $e^{-\lambda}. \qquad$